# Why does a code keeps running endlessly after a certain number of iterations?

Tags: c, sum, integer, primes

Please consider this C Code

```
void main() {
    int i, s = 17;
    for (i = 8; i < 2000000; i++) {
        if (ifprime(i))
            s += i;
    }
    printf("%d", s);
}
```

It won't run with this number of iterations but produces some result with lower iterations like `while (i < 200000)`

Why is that?

(Note that I am not asking for a solution, Many thanks)

Comment: Isn't is just because there are larger gaps between the prime numbers? (and if you are searching for prime numbers, you don't need to check even numbers)

Comment: What do you mean by "won't run"? Does the program crash? Have you tried to catch the crash in a debugger?

Comment: By running endlessly, do you mean that it outputs numbers above the upper bound, or do you mean that it just takes a long time? Because for such large numbers it will take a very long time.

Comment: @some yeah i know man but i am asking in general because i have encountered this problem many times

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry for that, yes it runs but endlessly yeah with no output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to overflow with 32 bit integers. That's undefined behavior and while that typically won't cause your program to run endlessly, that's a possibility, because there's no guarantee whatsoever on what happens when your program exhibits undefined behavior. Try `long long` instead, which is at least 64 bit (for the signed version, that's at least 63 bits and one sign bit).

```
long long s = 17;
```

And print it this way:

```
printf("%lld", s);
```

This unoptimized version of a prime number search will take quite a while for all numbers up to `2000000`, so perhaps you just think it's running endlessly when it isn't. I recommend debugging by putting a print like `if (i % 1000 == 0) printf("%d %lld\n", i, s);` into the loop, then you can see how far along it is and if it is still working. For me, it's working (with that `long long` fix, of course).

Comment: Never considered debugging because i've always thought of it as a hardware limitation, now i see ! thank you so much man

Comment: @chqrlie sometimes I forget that there are at least some guarantees on integer sizes. :) thanks for the hint, it's fixed now.

Comment: OK, it is actually at least 63 value bits plus a sign bit :)

Answer (score 1):

because you know that will be positive you can use

```
unsigned long long s = 17;
```

and then print it with

```
printf("%llu",s);
```

also you can use that for i